# using moment.js to set initial time zone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I try to follow **moment.js** to init specify `eastern 8` time zone.

I change my os time zone to `western 4`, then I input the same timestamp as below.

```
moment().utcOffset(-240);
moment(1473998400000).toDate();

moment().utcOffset(480);
moment(1473998400000).toDate();

// both output >>> Fri Sep 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

but I can't understand that why I also get the same output from different initial timezone?

what I did wrong :(

Comment: Setting `utcOffset` only changes the behavior of the `moment` object.  It doesn't change the instant in time you're talking about, and therefore doesn't result you get from `toDate`, since the `Date` object only works with local time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

First, don't use `.toDate()`, or you will receive a JavaScript `Date` object and you will have to convert it by yourself.

Second, you need to call `.utcOffset()` on the initialized moment object.

```
moment(1473998400000).utcOffset(-240).format(); // 2016-09-16T00:00:00-04:00
moment(1473998400000).utcOffset(480).format();  // 2016-09-16T12:00:00+08:00
```

Also, check the following excerpt from the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/):

> If you want an actual time zone -- time in a particular location, like
>   America/Los_Angeles, consider [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I try `moment-timezone` but also get the same output. in my opinion, it could help me convert timestamp to correct timezone as I initial setting, but now I don't know how to fix :(

Comment: thanks for your reply, I plan to use `moment-timezone` now :)